# Spark in local mode for production

Tags: java, json, apache-spark-sql

Working on a platform where most of the datasets are in json format but with little support for a query language to filter, join and ...

Looking at SparkSQL APIs and examples seems like a good solution for the issue. Considering that, as of now, we don't need a full-fledged Spark installation I'm considering embedding it in the app and running it in local mode. Any thoughts?

Comment: So your question is just the part `Considering that, as of now, we don't need a full-fledged Spark installation I'm considering embedding it in the app and running it in local mode. Any thoughts?`. Correct? The rest seems unrelated. Are you sure you need spark? Would you consider just turning the JSON into database tables? That way you can simply use SQL. Would probably find more help with that.

Comment: Here's a related discussion

http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/OSGI-bundles-for-spark-project-td10700.html

Comment: Which of the messages is related? Do you want anything specific in Spark? You said filter, join so I suggested converting the data to database tables

Comment: Here's the part that is related to my question:

No, you usually run Spark apps via the spark-submit script, and the 
Spark machinery is already deployed on a cluster. Although it's 
possible to embed the driver and get it working that way, it's not 
supported. 

On Fri, Feb 20, 2015 at 4:48 PM, Niranda Perera 
<[hidden email]> wrote:

> Hi Sean, 
> 
> does it mean that Spark is not encouraged to be embedded on other products? 
>

Comment: On a related topic, are there any good reasons not to use Spark Local Mode for production environments? I'm on a project where spark is the way to go, but currently we have a 128-core, 1TB RAM machine, and we want to know if we can use local Mode on that machine to avoid getting new machines for a cluster approach.

Comment: Has anybody successfully embedded spark in another application and has got some decent performance?